# Problem in YUI:I am using YUI grid,my dataset contains some special character.i bind my dataset into grid,but its not displayed in my grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, yui, yui-grids

Problem in YUI:I am using YUI grid,my dataset contains some special character.i bind my dataset into the grid,but its not displayed in my grid?

how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data through `HtmlEncode`.

If that fails, report a bug to Yahoo.

Comment: Search MSDN for that function, it is accessible from many places.